# Apache 2.4 service failed to start

Tags: service, apache-2.4

Apache 2.4 service start error.

I installed Apache 2.4 on windows 2008 R2 server.  In the httpd.conf I added a directory configuration.

```
<Directory "M:">
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Apache service failed to start.  If I comment out the whole "Directory" block the service started no problem.

The M drive is the mapped network drive.  the account used to start Apache service has been granted as logon as service, act as operating system.

The eventlogs error:

```
The apache service named reported the following error:  <Directory "M:"> is invalid.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried "Directory M:/"?

Answer (score 1):

[The Apache documentation warns that you should only use UNC paths in the configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#windrivemap), and avoid attempting to use drive letters. If you must use a drive letter, append the `/` at the end, e.g. `M:/`.